# how to print underscore as it is from double type of variable

Tags: java, java-7

Explanation with example:
Current output of below mention method code gives:

```
--New use  of hyphen in JDK7 say ex. value (2453233.3) is ----2453233.3
```

But i want output like

```
--New use  of hyphen in JDK7 say ex. value (2_45_323_3.300_00) is ----2453233.3
```

How to get this output? please help me
Method is here

```
 public   void sayhi()
{   double hypdouble= 2_45_323_3.300_00;  
    System.out.println("--New use  of hyphen in JDK7 say ex. value ("+Double.toString(hypdouble)+") is ----"+hypdouble);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing. **The underscore literal is just for source code, it is represented the exact same way in memory and in byte code.** You will have to use a custom format to print it out the way you want.

Comment: thank you sir. I like your name 'Sotirios Delimanolis' . very unique name

Answer (score 0):

Underscore literals can be used to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code. It does not provide the feature to increase the readability of your code output.

I believe you will have have write your own logic to display the output in your desired format.